# Rails: Showing Error Messages [bootstrap-sass, formtastic]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

I'm using Bootstrap-Sass along with Formstatic. I thought an error message should be automatically shown next to the field with Formstatic like in this picture: [image: here]
<sub>(source: [asciicasts.com](http://asciicasts.com/system/photos/227/original/E185I06.png))</sub>

But even if the user puts an invalid input, my app does not show an error message. This seems to be an easy problem but I cant figure out the reason behind.

**PostController**

```
# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
  def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.view = 0
@post.like = 0
@post.hate = 0

respond_to do |format| 
  if @post.save
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], order: 'like desc', per_page: 10) 
    format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
    format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

**PostModel**

```
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true,
                      :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 300}
```

**_form (Post)**

```
<% @post = Post.new %>
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.semantic_errors :name %>
<%= f.inputs do %>
     <%= f.input :name, :label => 'name' %>
     <%= f.input :content, :label => 'body' %>
<% end %>
<%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :button_html => { :class => "btn btn-primary" }, :as => :button  %>
    <%= f.action :cancel, :as => :link %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE:** In PostController, I deleted the following two lines

```
    #format.html { render action: "new" }
    #format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

and added

```
    render @post.errors
```

Then, I got

```
@messages={:name=>["can't be blank"], :content=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]}>
```

**So the problem is that the way I'm rendering json is wrong. Could someone help me how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass presence validation in `name` and `content` and length validation in content that means if you don't enter any value in `name` or `content` then it will give error like `can't be blank` and if `content` value length is less than 10 and greater then 300 then it will give error.

If you want to pass validation for invalid input then you have to pass [validates_format_of](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of) validation.

You puts invalid input in name or content? 
Can you provide invalid input that you enter?

**Update**

```
 # in /config/initializers/formtastic_config.rb. 

 Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder.inline_errors = :sentence
```

**See Video** : http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

**Get Code**  : https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-185

Comment: 1) I leave all the fields blank and press "create"
2) I write less than 10 for the content field and press "create"
These two must stop me from saving the post, and they do. But they do not throw the error messages. In other words, the validation is working correctly but showing error messages is not working. How do I make it work?

Comment: Why don't you try validates :name, :presence => :true in your model ? There are message modifiers also .

Comment: I'm confused because I already have that in my model and no error message is showing. It validates correctly because the post is not saved if the conditions are not met, but it's just that the error messages are not showing

Comment: @Dipak I think f.error_messages is outdated, as it didn't work. According to [this](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), <%= f.semantic_errors :name %> is the correct form, but I still haven't figured out why it's not working. Is there a problem with the way I render/redirect in the PostController in case the post isn't saved because of validation problem?

Comment: @MaximusS try this i update it, use :sentence for none, and if still not working then comment that line then test

Comment: @Dipak Are you sure that it's formtastic_config.rb? because there is formtastic.rb in config/initializers already

Comment: Nothing happens. It just renders to the "new" action without showing error messages.

Comment: @MaximusS can you post your code into github, i will pull it and check it out. and send me that url - my email address is 11dipak.contact@gmail.com. if it is possible

Comment: Thank you for your support! I will try to figure out by myself more first!

Comment: I still couldn't figure out the solution. I will post another question